# Microsoft SQL Server on linux container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, containers

I installed the following SQL Server on a Linux Container as this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash
But when I am trying to connect from outside I get the following errors:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error 
has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For 
more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

From inside the container I am able to connect either as localhost either from the container;s ip.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps -a`, especially the PORTS section? What command or connection string are you using to test connectivity from outside the container?

Comment: 53c490d0a1ac        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   11 hours ago        Up 34 seconds       1433/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1435->1435/tcp   sqldocker

Comment: sqlcmd -S xxxxxx,1435 -U SA -P "xxxxxxx"

Comment: Seems like you have a port typo. Unless you've configured SQL Server differently it will be listening on port 1433. If there's some reason you want to keep port 1435 externally you could use `-p 1435:1433` on the docker run line, but to prevent surprises down the track you might want to stick with `-p 1433:1433`.